# Securing connection credentials on a web server

Tags: webserver, databases, password-policy, file-encryption

I'm in process of creating a tiny blog platform and I've encountered a pretty controversial topic of storing connection string to a DB securely on a host. Here is a reference question: [How to encrypt database connection credentials on a web server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22817/how-to-encrypt-database-connection-credentials-on-a-web-server).

As of my question: I thought of storing credentials in gpg-encrypted file somewhere in `/etc` folder of Ubuntu 14.04 host. Whenever server starts it would prompt a sysadmin (me) to decrypt a file and then there is need of a service that would run in a background waiting for a site back-end to query it for a connection string. Then it would return all the necessary for DB connection information and back-end would proceed with querying a DB itself.

IMO with this approach the only place where a password is stored on up-and-running server is RAM. Whenever server crashes because of malicious attack or attackers managed to dump web root they still can't get the password as password granting service works on a system level.

Is it a good security scheme? What alternatives would you propose (Python Flask, MySQL and peewee)? Also if my idea is not that bad how can I implement that "service" to run in a background and wait for a credentials query (preferably some kind of a bash script)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good security scheme?

Yes, it is reasonable.  Usually people don't do this because they want automated systems, and the downtime caused by needing to manually enter a password every time the app restarts is beyond what they'd consider acceptable.

> What alternatives would you propose (Python Flask, MySQL and peewee)?

Basically all the things mentioned in [the question you linked to](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/22817/16960).  Personally, I'm a fan of [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/), which is a separate HTTP server that stores your secrets.  It's not at all a perfect solution: you still have to authenticate to *it*, which practically means you end up with a temporary session token that you store in plaintext on your server.

> Also if my idea is not that bad how can I implement that "service" to run in a background and wait for a credentials query (preferably some kind of a bash script)?

With programming?  You're probably going to want to just do this in your application code as part of its startup process.

Comment: Thanks for the Vault link - it's an interesting thing to investigate. As of implementation, I'm interested in how to make running bash script -> process to accept requests and answer (just like a web server) locally.

Comment: As you say, it's just like any web service.  Bash is probably the wrong choice there, but you can find people writing web servers in bash.